# How to change VARCHAR type to DATETIME using ALTER in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

How can I change `VARCHAR()` type to `DATETIME` using `ALTER` in Postgresql?

The column data is already structured like: `"2013-12-08 16:09:07"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the [`USING` clause to `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... TYPE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html), and [the `to_timestamp` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  ALTER COLUMN thecolumn 
   TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 
     USING to_timestamp(thecolumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

In this case as the data looks like it's already a valid timestamp you can probably simplify it with a cast instead:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  ALTER COLUMN thecolumn 
   TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 
     USING to_timestamp(thecolumn::timestamp with time zone);
```

You will note that I've used the type name "timestamp with time zone" instead of "datetime". That's because in PostgreSQL, `datetime` is just an alias for `timestamp without time zone`... but in most cases you actually want to use `timestamp with time zone` instead. To learn more about timestamps, [see the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).